# Best way to store list of numbers and to retrieve them

Tags: database, search, random

What is the best way to store a list of random numbers (like lotto/bingo numbers) and retrieve them? I'd like to store on a Database a number of rows, where each row contains 5-10 numbers ranging from 0 to 90. I will store a big number of those rows. What I'd like to be able is to retrieve the rows that have at least X number in common to a newly generated row.

Example:

```
[3,4,33,67,85,99]
[55,56,77,89,98,99]
[3,4,23,47,85,91]
```

Those are on the DB

I will generate this:
`[1,2,11,45,47,88]` and now I want to get the rows that have at least 1 number in common with this one.

The easiest (and dumbest?) way is to make 6 select and check for similar results.

I thought to store numbers with a large binary string like
`000000000000000000000100000000010010110000000000000000000000000` with 99 numbers where each number represent a number from 1 to 99, so if I have 1 at the 44th position, it means that I have 44 on that row. This method is probably shifting the difficult tasks to the Db but it's again not very smart.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a table like so:

```
TicketId Number
1        3
1        4
1        33
1        67
1        85
1        99
2        55
2        56
2        77
etc...
```

Then your query, at least for X = 1, becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TicketId FROM Ticket WHERE Number IN (1, 2, 11, 45, 47, 88)
```

The advantage of this is that you can use an index instead of a full table scan.

For X greater than one, you could do the following:

```
SELECT TicketId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Ticket WHERE Number IN (1, 2, 11, 45, 47, 88)
GROUP BY TicketId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Again this will be able to use the index.

Comment: +1, be sure to make the PK TicketId+Number, and put another index on  Number only

Comment: Very simple and very smart. Or the question was too dumb. ;)

Comment: @Mark Byers: Thx for an update. btw, can u tell why u need to remove union all? I think it's faster than "IN" command.

Comment: @vcha: Perhaps it's faster, I don't know... but either way it seems like an unnecessary performance optimization here, especially since I haven't profiled it.